# text alignment in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

i will like to align my text so that when i send a message, it appears on the left, but its a reply, the text appears on the right ... i dont know whether to use "text-align:left", position or align. here is my code

```
if ($row['username'] == $username)
{
    $color = 'blue';
    $align:left; // dont know if this is right

}
else
{
    $color = 'red';
    $align:right; // dont know if this is right
}


echo '<i><p style="font-family:arial;color:'.$color.';font-size:15px;"> <strong>' . $row['username']. '</strong>: ' . $mymessage.'</i></p>';

}
```

Comment: try using float: right or float:left

Comment: `$align:left;` is incorrect PHP statement

Comment: or generate special class for element in php code and define this class in css.

Comment: @E_ERROR its kinda hilarious that your username is what PHP would generate with that statement

Answer (score 4):

Set it exactly the same way you're setting color.

For instance:

```
$align='right';

echo '<i><p style="font-family:arial;color:'.$color.';text-align:'.$align.';font-size:15px;"> <strong>' . $row['username']. '</strong>: ' . $mymessage.'</i></p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$css =  ($row['username'] == $username) ? 'color:blue;text-align:left;' : 'color:red;text-align:right;';

echo '<i><p style="font-family:arial;font-size:15px;'.$css.'"> <strong>' . $row['username']. '</strong>: ' . $mymessage.'</i></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if ($row['username'] == $username)
{
    $color = 'blue';
    $align = 'left';

}
else
{
    $color = 'red';
    $align = 'right';
}


echo '<i><p style="text-align:' . $align . ';font-family:arial;color:'.$color.';font-size:15px;"> <strong>' . $row['username']. '</strong>: ' . $mymessage.'</i></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
if ($row['username'] == $username)

echo '<i><p style="font-family:arial;color:blue;float:left;font-size:15px;"> <strong>' . $row['username']. '</strong>: ' . $mymessage.'</i></p>';

else
echo '<i><p style="font-family:arial;color:red;float:right;font-size:15px;"> <strong>' . $row['username']. '</strong>: ' . $mymessage.'</i></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if you use CSS classes for that.

For example, you could have a class `message` and a class `reply`:

```
<style>

.message {
  color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}

.reply {
  color: red;
  text-align: right;
}

</style>
```

And then in PHP:

```
if ($row['username'] == $username)
{
  $class = "message";
}
else
{
  $class = "reply";
}


echo "<p class='$class'>
  <strong>{$row['username']}</strong>: $mymessage
</p>';
```

Your code will look *way* more clean.